# Service injection in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am new to AngularJS and I can't seem to figure out what went wrong with my service injection.

**Service -- ErrorTranslatorForApiCalls.js**

```
(function() {
    var errorTranslatorModule = angular.module('exceptionHandler');

    errorTranslatorModule.factory('apiStatusTranslator', function() {
        var translateStatusToFriendlyMessage = function (status) {

            var friendlyMessage = "Error occured while performing the action";

            switch (status) {
            case 401:
                friendlyMessage =  "You are unauthorized to perform this action";
                break;
            }

            return friendlyMessage;
        };

        return {
            translateStatusToFriendlyMessage : translateStatusToFriendlyMessage
        };
    });
});
```

**Here is where I injected it -- GroupSearch.js**

```
(function () {

    agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

    var module = angular.module('groupEditor', ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "agGrid", "exceptionHandler"]);

    module.constant('BASEURL', 'http://localhost/XXX.XXX.XXX/api/group/');
    module.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'BASEURL', "apiStatusTranslator", function ($scope, $resource, BASEURL, apiStatusTranslator) { ............ REST OF CODE GOES HERE;
```

**My HTML JavaScript includes**

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Services/ErrorTranslatorForApiCalls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/GroupSearch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you wrap your service into a separate module, I wouldn't do that for one application. But anyway, your code looks fine. What says it in the console output? And what is `agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);`?

Comment: I think that you need to inject it once at the module declaration. Try to inject errortrans....

Comment: I was missing the *closure* () of my anonymous function in * ErrorTranslatorForApiCalls.js*

Comment: you never inject the service

Answer (score 0):

As a user suggested, console error print would help here. However, if what you put in code block is exactly your code, there is an error. You are missing "])" at the end in your controller code.

```
 module.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'BASEURL', "apiStatusTranslator", function ($scope, $resource, BASEURL, apiStatusTranslator) { }

])//This is missing
```